# .htaccess rewrite to redirect a redundant URL to non-redundant URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I tried to write generic .htaccess commands, so that I could make the below to happen; however not to any success so far.

```
www.mysite.com/x/x/      Redirects to   www.mysite.com/x/
www.mysite.com/x/y/y/    Redirects to   www.mysite.com/x/y/
www.mysite.com/x/y/y/x/  Redirects to   www.mysite.com/x/
```

Please note that I'm trying to make this very generic, i.e. x and y can be any directory names. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Diwakar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apply following redirects in your htaccess

```
  Redirect 301 /x/x/ /x/
  Redirect 301 /x/y/y/ /x/y/
  Redirect 301 /x/y/y/x/ /x/
```

Comment: Thanks, it works out for me the way you demonstrated!!